# Ground for dropping the article the

Tags: grammar, usage

"The input activates this innate structure, but only input of a very specific kind (i + 1) will be useful in altering a learner’s grammar."

What is the ground for omitting the article "the" before the word "input", as in "input of a very specific" in the above sentence?

Answer (score 2):

"The" identifies a specific case of something.  "The input" at the beginning of the sentence refers to a particular input, which is what "activates this innate structure".

The second input in the sentence refers generically to all things that are inputs.  Within that category of stuff, "only a very specific kind will be useful".

When a word like "input" is used generically to describe a category or type of thing, it doesn't get an article.

Comment: My confusion arose when I  found  "the" omitted even after "of" was used after it. This use of 'input' in the phrase "only input of a very specific kind"  doesn't make it a specific case of something, as in "the water of the pond", "the reputation of the company", etc.?

Comment: @Mexal, no,  The "of" phrase is just a clarification of what is being referred to.  You can narrow the scope and still be talking generically about a type of something, or you can narrow it so far that you are talking about a single thing.  For example, you could say either "the water in the pond" if you were referring to that water to the exclusion of all other water, or "water in the pond" if you were referring to that type of substance.  "Water in the pond evaporates but pebbles at the bottom don't".  (cont'd)

Comment: "The reputation of the company" narrows it down to a single reputation.  I have a hard time contriving a scenario where that could be a generic reference.  In your question, "only" provides perspective that input is used generically and the only example that works is the stated one.